# Post request restarts server without sending data (Angular2 / Node.js)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, angular

Here is my code;

SERVICE:

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Http, Headers, RequestOptions } from "@angular/http";
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";
import 'rxjs/Rx';

import {Heatmap} from "./heatmap"

@Injectable()
export class HeatmapService {
 constructor (private _http: Http) {}

    signup(heatmap: Heatmap) {
        const body = JSON.stringify(heatmap);
        const headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
        const options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

        return this._http.post('http://localhost:8080/create', body, options)
            .map(response => response.json())
            .catch(error => Observable.throw(error.json()));
    }
}
```

Component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, FormControl, Validators } from "@angular/forms";

import { Heatmap } from "./heatmap";
import { HeatmapService } from "./heatmap.service";

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'js/app/heatmap/heatmap.component.html'
})

export class heatmapComponent implements OnInit {

    myForm: FormGroup;

    constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder, public heatService: HeatmapService) {}

    onSubmit() {
        const heatmap = new Heatmap(this.myForm.value.name, this.myForm.value.data, this.myForm.value.country);
        console.log(heatmap)

        this.heatService.sendData(heatmap)
            .subscribe(
                data => console.log(data),
                error => console.error(error)
            )
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.myForm = this.formBuilder.group({
            name: ['', Validators.required],
            data: ['', Validators.required],
            country: ['', Validators.required]
        });
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">name</label>
        <input type="text" id="name" class="form-control" formControlName="name">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="data">data</label>
        <input type="text" id="data" class="form-control" formControlName="data">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="country">country</label>
        <input type="text" id="country" class="form-control" formControlName="country">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" [disabled]="!myForm.valid">Sign Up</button>
</form>
```

Heatmap:

```
export class Heatmap {
    constructor(public name: string, public data: string, public country: string){}
}
```

The problem:

Each time I submit my form my server restarts automatically with no data logged, and doesn't give me time to look at any errors being consoled.

The only error I get is output from gulp -

error TS2339: Property 'sendData' does not exist on type 'HeatmapService'.

Hope someone can help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you submit your form, you call `this.heatService.sendData(heatmap)....` in you onSubmit() function.

If you've pasted the whole `HeatmapService`, there is no `sendData` method. That's exactly what the error says.

Either create this method or copy/paste it into your question.

Comment: Oh you're right sorry, I was trying to do it like `        this.heatService(heatmap)` this before which I saw work in some tutorials. I just made the connection.

Answer (score 1):

Well the error message is pretty obvious. 
Looking at your Heatmap class I can see there is no sendData method defined, that is why you get that error.